# How to calculate sum of difference of a row value with respect other rows value excluding the row in particular using window function

Tags: mysql, window-functions

How to calculate sum of difference of a row value with respect other rows value excluding the row in particular using window function.

For ex : Roll no ,total marks for student table given

Roll total marks

1      50  ------------- > calculated as abs(50-60)+abs(50-70)==30

2      60  -------------> calculated as abs(60-50)+abs(60-70)==20

3      70 -------------> calculated as abs(70-50)+abs(70-60)==30

and we have to calculate sum of (absolute difference  of total marks with  respect to other students)for  every student  .

Comment: Only MySQL 8 has window functions, tag this with the version you're using.  You can do it with a join instead, does it Have to be a window function?

Comment: It really should not matter, even if you include the current row (marks) value; because **ABS(difference)** will be 0 in that case, and will not affect the **SUM**.

Comment: Unless you have to do this with a window function for some reason a cross join would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

It really should not matter, even if you include the current row (marks) value; because **ABS(difference)** will be 0 in that case, and will not affect the **SUM**.

Anyways, in your case, a simple "Self-Join" using condition that `t1.roll_no <> t2.roll_no` should suffice, with a `Group By`:

```
SELECT
  t1.roll_no, 
  t1.marks, 
  SUM(ABS(t1.marks - t2.marks)) AS sum_abs_difference 
FROM 
  your_table_name AS t1 
JOIN your_table_name AS t2 
  ON t2.roll_no <> t1.roll_no 
GROUP BY t1.roll_no, t1.marks
```